# What does the 'hide-identity' gsetting do?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, privacy

On Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 I have just noticed that there is a `hide-identity` gsetting:

[image: hide-identity gsetting in dconf-editor]

I have read its description, but what exactly would be the difference if I turned it on? What information would it stop showing and where exactly? And would turning this option cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Before GNOME 3.10, the user menu in the top right of the screen showed the user name in the top bar by default.

[image: GNOME 3.8 user menu]

There was a privacy setting to turn that feature off.

[image: GNOME 3.8 privacy settings]

When the user menu was redesigned in GNOME 3.10, the user name was hidden by default from the top bar. I don't think that setting is user for anything now and it was removed from the **Settings** app.

Comment: It says `on screen or on the *network*`, so what about the latter?

Comment: Plus, this setting in gsettings is disabled by default and I am on 3.20 so the above in your answer probably isn't really relevant to this.